# Autosize Button with an image

Tags: c#, wpf, button

How to make a buttons auto-size with an image instead of fixing a default button size? Thanks really appreciated.

All my buttons are fixed size, I need to have some buttons buttons to be big, some small depending on the image size.

heres my codes:

```
 Button tba = new Button();
            tba.FontSize = 19;
            tba.Height = 300
            tba.MinWidth = 100;
           //tba.Height = Double.NaN;
           //tba.Width = Double.NaN;
            ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();

            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(@"files.png" + lstQuestion[i].ImageURL.Substring(1), UriKind.Absolute);
            bitmap.EndInit();
            brush.ImageSource = bitmap;
            tba.Background = brush;
            wrapPanel1.Children.Add(tba);
```

Comment: you can bind them to properties with INPC and use that ... otherwise, this is a very poorly asked question

Comment: **Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for.**

Comment: So if you have a big image then you want the button to be big? If so I would start by removing the explicit button width and height.

Comment: no i have many images button , but some button i need to enlarge bigger, so is better to say want to adjust according to images file size

Comment: @user3044300 I edited your question to reflect your last comment - your question was confusing before, is it now as you originaly intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To size the button to the image: host the image in an `Image` and set [`Image.Strech`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.stretch(v=vs.110).aspx) to None and remove the sizes from your `Button`:

```
Button tba = new Button();
Image myImage = new Image();
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.BeginInit();
bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(@"files.png" + lstQuestion[i].ImageURL.Substring(1), UriKind.Absolute);
bitmap.EndInit();
myImage.Source = myBitmapImage;
myImage.Stretch = Stretch.None;
tba.Content = myImage;
```

If you want more than just an image in your `Button` add the image to panel that will let the image fill the space, e.g. a `Grid`, then set `Button.Content` to that panel.

Incidentally in XAML you can just go:

```
<Button>
    <Image Strech="None" Source=".\Water Lilies.jpg"/>
</Button>
```